# How to combine -vf and -filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I combine `-vf` and `-filter_complex` in this command?

```
ffmpeg -i test2.mp4 -s 1080x1920 -i igoverlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25" -s 1080x1920 -vf "scale=w=1080:h=-1:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1080:1920:color=white:y=(oh-ih)/2" -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://STREAM_URL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Combined:

```
ffmpeg -i test2.mp4 -i igoverlay.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=w=1080:h=-1:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1080:1920:color=white:y=(oh-ih)/2[bg];[bg][1]overlay=25:25,fps=30,format=yuv420p" -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -f flv rtmp://STREAM_URL;
```